# Eclipse (JBoss Developer Studio) not automatically building JPA metamodel classes

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jpa, metamodel

I have a Maven project set up that has a parent and two child modules:

```
parent
    business
    support
```

All of my JPA entities are in the support module. I've decided I want to use JPA metamodel classes to provide type safety when I use the Criteria API. I made changes to the pom.xml for the support module (see below) and the metamodel classes are being created correctly in `support/target/metamodel` when I build from the command line using `mvn clean install`. Builds work and deployable artifacts work when deployed.

The issue is that when I follow the instructions [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html) (which mirrors many other places) on how to set up Eclipse to build the metamodel classes, Eclipse doesn't seem to do anything. It creates the support/target/metamodel directory but there's never anything in it. I've cleaned inside Eclipse, from the command line using `mvn clean`, done Maven->Update Project multiple times but nothing seems to work.

What am I missing?

Here's what my support project's properties look like.

[image]

The relavant section of my support module's pom.xml is:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- source output directory -->
                        <outputDirectory>target/metamodel</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>target/metamodel</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Version information:

Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio
Version: 10.2.0.GA
Build id: GA-v20161125-1418-B55
Build date: 20161125-1418

Java 1.8.0_112

Maven (command line): 3.3.9

Maven (Eclipse - m2e): 1.7.120161104-1805 embedded version 3.3.9

Answer (score 4):

This is the setup that has worked for me.

I did not use the org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin, rather set up the maven-compiler-plugin for annotation processing. The issues mentioned in the [instructions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html), i.e. [MCOMPILER-62](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-62) and [MCOMPILER-66](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-66), are now closed, so I see no reason why to bother with the org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin.

Another notable difference is the "Factory Path", in the Eclipse configuration.

### pom.xml

A minimal setup to get started. Note the maven-compiler-plugin configuration.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>scratch</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpa</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <version.plugin.maven.compiler>3.5</version.plugin.maven.compiler>
        <version.hibernate>5.2.5.Final</version.hibernate>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.plugin.maven.compiler}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <annotationProcessors>
                        <annotationProcessor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                    </annotationProcessors>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                            <version>${version.hibernate}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${version.hibernate}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

You may want to run it once by hand or download hibernate-jpamodelgen by hand (e.g. `mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:5.2.5.Final`), so that the JAR is available for the Eclipse configuration.

### Eclipse configuration

1. Go to project properties (project context menu → Properties or Alt+Enter)
2. Select "Java Compiler" → "Annotation Processing"
3. Check the following:

   - "Enable project specific settings"
   - "Enable annotation processing"
   - "Enable processing in editor"
4. Generated source directory: `target/generated-sources/annotations/`
   (this is where Maven puts them by default)
5. Select "Factory Path"
6. Add the following external jars, from your Maven repository (`hibernate-jpamodelgen` version will probably vary):

   - `org/hibernate/hibernate-jpamodelgen/5.2.5.Final/hibernate-jpamodelgen-5.2.5.Final.jar`
   - `javax/persistence/persistence-api/1.0.2/persistence-api-1.0.2.jar`
7. Add the generated sources folder (as configured in step 4) to the Java source folders (Java build path → Source tab → Add Folder...)
8. A clean-build of the project may be required afterwards

Answer (score 1):

**This will work for eclipse 2019-06 or later versions:**

According to Jboss documentation, it is not required to explicitly set the processor plugin, since the metamodel classes are created automatically on Maven build in **\target\generated-sources\annotations** project's folder (since JDK 1.6).

Thus, you only need to make sure the **Annotation Processing** refers to this target folder, as in here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in case you are going to use a recent eclipse with Java 11, you will meet the issue that the javamodel is not generated even specifying the hibernate-jpamodelgen in annotation processing of eclipse.
If you check the error tabs you will see this: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

this is due the fact that it has been removed in Java 11, so to fix it you should
add also the jar jaxb-api on the factory path with hibernate-jpamodelgen.

I leave this here for anyone that could meet the same problems I had (and for me when I search again and have forgot about this)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix this issue is to do a "mvn clean install", which will create the metamodel in the target directory, then use the metamodel generated as the source folder as below

[image]

After you do the above step, your project structure should look like below

[image]